# Is there such a thing of an input() send over socket.sendto()? UDP or TCP

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, udp

I'm learning socket programming and one of the task is for the server to reply to the client asking a question. The client would then reply to the server. Then the server would take it's input and store it in a variable.

I was wondering if there is something like an input() to be send over socket.sendto()? From the task it would be a server asking a question and providing a input() for the client to reply/respond.

Not sure if this is important but it's over UDP. I'm guessing TCP should be the same?

The gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
serverSocket.sendto(input(somemessage.encode()), clientAddress)
```

I'm guessing obviously that doesn't work because we're sending bytes over UDP not a function.

Comment: The equivalent of `input()` is `socket.recv()`

Comment: would this be the client end?
```ServerReply, serverAddress = clientsocket.recv(bufsize)```

Comment: Sorry I meant that but that wasn't what I was asking. I was to say the server asking for an input from the client and the client typing out something which is then stored in a variable on the server. If that makes sense.

Comment: TCP connections aren't interactive, they're just network streams. You just send and receive data, but there's nothing analogous to prompts like the `input()` function has. UDP just sends and receives datagrams, again with no concept of interactivity.

Comment: You can of course design an application protocol where you send a message containing a prompt, the other system displays that prompt to the user, asks for input, and then sends back what the user typed. But this is not built into sockets in any way.

Comment: Oh I see. Now I get it. Thanks! Apologies for the question then.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can use `input()` function along with sockets

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
#create a udp socket
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)     

question = "whats your favourite color?"    

#send your query to server
client_socket.sendto(question.encode("utf-8"),(server_addr,server_port))

#receive reply from server assuming reply is not bigger than 1024 bytes
reply,address = client_socket.recvfrom(1024)

print(reply)
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
#create a udp socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

#bind new socket to an ip address and port
server_socket.bind((server_ip,server_port))

#receive client query
msg,address = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))

#let the guy sitting on server reply through standard io
query_reply = input()   
#send query reply to client 
server_socket.sendto(query_reply.encode("utf-8"),address)
```